# Xamarin Android on orientation change keep content

Tags: android, xamarin, orientation

I would like to keep the same content either the orientation is vertical or horizontal. I noticed that the content initializes when the orientation change. I don' t want that. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your activity's attribute section add the following attributes and it should work for your ;

```
[Activity(....ConfigurationChanges = 
ConfigChanges.Orientation |
ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
 public class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity
```

Every activity where you want this to happen you will have add this in the header attributes